# Was Birgitte Silverbow remembering herself?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

Given the cyclical nature of the The Wheel of Time, it seems inevitable that everything has occurred before at some point. When Birgitte Silverbow finds herself

> ripped from *Tel'aran'rhiod* by Moghedien and bonded as Elayne's warder,

she says the following:

> "A Warder," Birgitte said slowly. "I think I remember hearing a tale
>   of a female Warder, but it was in a life so long ago that I cannot
>   remember more than that."

The Age of Legends did not have Warders, and the Forsaken stated that they did not even understand how the unique link worked. Therefore, it would seem that Birgitte is remembering something from a far-distant Age.

**Has Robert Jordan or anyone else 'official' commented on whether or not Birgitte is remembering herself.. that is, her current iteration from before?**

Comment: I think you're overestimating it. She lived many times in the Third Age - the one the action of books happen. Quite probably she wasn't  one of the Heroes in previous iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked to Jordan before,

> **QUESTION** When Birgitte says she remembers a tale of a female Warder after being bonded to Elayne, does she remember herself?
>
> **ROBERT JORDAN** RAFO. (read and find out)

[number 9](https://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kw=Birgitte)

So it appears we never find out if this is the case, but it does seem to really fit.

Comment: Seems like he was pretty quick to say NO on stuff that was flat-out wrong, so him saying RAFO leads me to believe the answer is yes. I guess he meant to explain it later on in the books that Sanderson wrote.

Comment: @Omegacron he would  have had to write about 100 more books to answer all of the RAFO's lol. but yeah he usually would flat out say NO if it was wrong, RAFO, seem to me to be more of a "possibly yes, maybe yes, i might use this in the future, i just havnt thought that far out yet, i dont want to get accused of lying if i change my mind" kind of a deal, his catch all for (I dont personally know yet?!  and spoilers lol)